# How to prevent from decreasing below 0 and Port Mapping

Tags: vhdl

I am coding for an accelerator and speedometer. I am currently trying to prevent the speedometer and transmission from decreasing below 0 and to stay at 0. I believe I can create if statements that will keep it above 0, but is there a more efficient way to do this. I am also trying to port map the speedometer to two 7 segment displays using code for operation on a FPGA. If you can help, I would appreciate it. Thank you. CODE EDITED

```
    LIBRARY IEEE;
USE IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.all;

ENTITY GearCounterFirst IS
PORT(
  CLK: IN STD_LOGIC;
  gas: IN STD_LOGIC;
  up: IN STD_LOGIC;
  down: IN STD_LOGIC;
  trans_o: OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (2 downto 0);
  speed_o: OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);
  acc_o: OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (4 downto 0));
 END GearCounterFirst;

ARCHITECTURE Behavior OF GearCounterFirst IS
    signal trans: std_logic_vector(2 downto 0) := "000";
    signal speed: std_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0) := "00000000";
    signal acc  : std_LOGIC_VECTOR(4 downto 0) := "00000";

BEGIN
    PROCESS (CLK) 

    BEGIN

    if (rising_edge(CLK)) then

            if (up = '1') then
                if (unsigned(trans) < 5) then
                    trans <= STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(unsigned(trans) + 1);
                elsif (unsigned(trans) = 5) then
                    trans <= trans;
                end if;

            elsif (down = '1') then
                if (unsigned (trans) > 0) then
                    trans <= STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(unsigned(trans) - 1);
                elsif (unsigned (trans) = 0) then
                    trans <= trans;
                end if;
            else 
                    trans <= trans; 
            end if;

        case trans is

            when "000" =>
                if (gas = '1') then
                    if (unsigned(speed) > 0) then
                        speed <= STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(unsigned(speed) - 2);
                        acc <= "00000";
                    elsif (unsigned(speed) = 0 ) then
                        speed <= speed;
                        acc <= "00000";
                    end if;
                elsif (gas = '0') then
                        if (unsigned(speed) > 0) then
                        speed <= STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(unsigned(speed) - 2);
                        acc <= "00000";
                        elsif (unsigned(speed) = 0 ) then
                        speed <= speed;
                        acc <= "00000";
                        end if;
                    end if;

            when "001" => -- Trans in 1st gear

                if (gas = '1') then    --gas is presed
                    if (unsigned(speed) < 15) then   -- Increase until 15
                        speed <= STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(unsigned(speed) + 5);
                        acc <= "11111";
                    end if;

                elsif (gas = '0') then   -- gas is not pressed
                    if (unsigned(speed) > 0) then    -- decrease until speed is 0
                        speed <= STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(unsigned(speed) - 2);   
                        acc <= "00000";
                    elsif (unsigned(speed) = 0) then    -- at 0 speed, stay at 0
                        speed <= "00000000";
                        acc <= "00000";
                    end if;
                end if; 


            when "010" => -- Trans in 2nd gear
                if (gas = '1') then
                    if (unsigned(speed) < 35) then
                        speed <= STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(unsigned(speed) + 4);
                        acc <= "01111";
                    end if;

                elsif (gas = '0') then
                        speed <= STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(unsigned(speed) - 2);
                        acc <= "00000";
                end if;

            when "011" =>   -- Trans in 3rd gear
                if (gas = '1') then
                    if (speed < 60) then
                        speed <= STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(unsigned(speed) + 3);
                        acc <= "00111";
                    end if;

                elsif (gas = '0') then
                    if (speed > 0) then
                        speed <= STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(unsigned(speed) - 2);
                        acc <= "00000";
                    end if;
                end if;


            when "101" =>   -- Trans in 4th gear
                if (gas = '1') then
                    speed <= STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(unsigned(speed) + 2);
                    acc <= "00011";

                elsif (gas = '0') then
                    speed <= STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(unsigned(speed) - 2);
                    acc <= "00000";
                end if;

            when "110" =>       -- Trans in 5th gear
                if (gas = '1') then
                    speed <= STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(unsigned(speed) + 1);
                    acc <= "00001";

                elsif (gas = '0') then
                    if (unsigned(speed) > 0) then
                    speed <= STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(unsigned(speed) - 2);
                    acc <= "00000";
                    elsif (unsigned(speed) = 0 ) then
                    speed <= speed;
                    acc <= "00000";
                    end if;
                end if;

            when others =>
                if (gas = '1') then
                    if (unsigned(speed) > 0) then
                        speed <= STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(unsigned(speed) - 2);
                        acc <= "00000";
                    elsif (unsigned(speed) = 0 ) then
                        speed <= speed;
                        acc <= "00000";
                    end if;
                elsif (gas = '0') then
                        if (unsigned(speed) > 0) then
                        speed <= STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(unsigned(speed) - 2);
                        acc <= "00000";
                        elsif (unsigned(speed) = 0 ) then
                        speed <= speed;
                        acc <= "00000";
                        end if;
                    end if;
        end case;
    end if;

    trans_o <= trans;
    acc_o <= acc;
    speed_o <= speed;
    END PROCESS;
End Behavior;
```

Comment: there is no reverse gear? ... Any practical way will involve "if" or something similar.

Comment: No, I just want to get this much working. As you let off the gas, the speed decreases, but it will decrease below 0 and that is not needed. I was wondering if there is a way, in declaration, to prevent it from going below 0 speed and transmission gear

Comment: Explain to us how the speed goes below zero as you let off the gas? Is it because you are trying to drive up a steep mountain and letting off the gas causes the engine to die and the car starts rolling down the mountain backwards?

Comment: Are you familiar with code comments?

Comment: EDITED-
when you let off the gas pedal, assuming flat terrain, and you come to a stop, no force will let your speed go negative. It will stay at 0 until you press the gas pedal again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, but I will give not a complete solution. This answer is intended as a short tutorial on how to solve this puzzle.

#### Preventing from decreasing below zero

1. Let's start with the case `trans = "110"` (fifth gear) and `gas = '0'`. Here, the `speed` drops by 1 unit every clock cycle. If speed has the current value 0, then the new value would be -1. But, as you have an `unsigned` it wraps to the highest value (255). So, which new value should be assigned in case the speed is already zero? Code this, e.g., using an `if` as indicated by Brian, near the actual decrement of `speed`. Check your implementation using simulation.
2. If you solved step 1, continue with the fourth gear. Here, you can decrement "below 0" in the case that the current speed is 1 or 0. Apply solution from step 1 in a similar way and check it by simulation.
3. Apply the scheme for all remaining gears and check it by simulation.
   Note, that you can also use relational operators in the `if` condition.
4. Think about the opposite case that the speed can also be incremented above the highest value (255) and thus wraps arounds to zero. Apply steps 1 to 3 accordingly.

I have to emphasize it again: **check every intermediate result by simulation** to detect coding errors early, before re-using code at another position.

#### Output on 7-segment display

1. You should start with new module which decodes a binary coded decimal (BCD, 4-bit) into the control lines of a 7-segment display (7-bit). This would just be combinational logic as no state has to be saved, so no clock is needed. Check your decoder by simulation and on a FPGA board, if you have one.
2. To display more than one decimal digit you have several options:

   - Extend decoder for hexadecimal numbers and use two of them for range 0 to 255 (0x0 to 0xFF).
   - Decode the 8-bit binary number to 12-bit BCD (3 digits à 4-bit). Then use 3 7-segment decoders.
   - Use a BCD counter for `speed` and `acc`. This is an advanced exercise but a good practice to understand digital logic.

#### Example testbench

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity GearCounterFirst_tb is
end entity GearCounterFirst_tb;

architecture sim of GearCounterFirst_tb is
  -- component ports
  signal CLK     : STD_LOGIC := '1';
  signal gas     : STD_LOGIC;
  signal up  : STD_LOGIC;
  signal down    : STD_LOGIC;
  signal trans_o : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (2 downto 0);
  signal speed_o : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);
  signal acc_o   : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (4 downto 0);

begin  -- architecture sim

  -- component instantiation
  DUT: entity work.GearCounterFirst
    port map (
      CLK     => CLK,
      gas     => gas,
      up      => up,
      down    => down,
      trans_o => trans_o,
      speed_o => speed_o,
      acc_o   => acc_o);

  -- clock generation
  CLK <= not CLK after 10 ns;

  -- waveform generation
  WaveGen_Proc: process
  begin
    gas <= '0';
    up <= '0';
    down <= '0';
    wait until falling_edge(clk);
    wait until falling_edge(clk);
    wait until falling_edge(clk);
    up <= '1';
    wait until falling_edge(clk);
    up <= '0';
    wait;
  end process;
end architecture;
```

Comment: Thank you very much Mr. Zabel. This was the initial approach I had thought of for the problem. I was going to use if speed > 0, then commence operations and if speed < 0; keep speed at 0. I was hoping, at a shot in the dark, that there might be a method in the initializing potion that would prevent this instead of using the "if less than" in multiple parts of the code. Thanks for the help though. I can code the transmission fine to the 7 segment code (at the bottom), but I will look into how to code the numbers higher than 4 bits for the speedometer. Thank you.

Comment: The code for using the if statements does not work as planned. I cannot check if the values are below say 15 for 1st gear. I tried:
If (speed < 15) then
....

I think I need to cast the number to do operations on, but It will not work correctly. I tried:

if (speed < STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(unsigned(15))

but only receive a list of errors stating that I am missing apostrophes or colons

Comment: @MarcusAshleyLowDBs You can use the relational operators only with the type `unsigned` in your example. That is, you must write `if (unsigned(speed) < 15) then`. Better is to change the datatype of `speed` to unsigned. Then you can save a lot of conversions in the additions and subtractions.

Comment: So the best route is to assign the signal speed: unsigned (7 downto 0) := "00000000";
Then when I am going to use it for output, typecast it back to STD_LOGIC_VECTOR

Comment: Thank you, I have figured it out. I have a bug that I have temporarily fixed that will set speed at 1 instead of 0, as initially keeping it at 0 causes it to fall below 0 into 255 instead of staying at 0. Thanks again

Comment: I have edited for step 1 in your process. I am only testing in 1st gear though. The code iterates into first gear, but persists to decrease below 0, without ever leaving first gear. I don't see how 5th could be affecting it. I am sorry if I am missing something that may be basic

Comment: @MarcusAshleyLowDBs Checking fifth gear first would require to init `trans` to "110". (Note you skipped `trans = "100"` in case). But anyway, your code is correct for 1st gear. I have checked it also by simulation with the testbench I have appended to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

For the below zero issue:
In a simpler form, just use two Case statements instead of one.  One Case that potentially increases the speed and one Case that potentially decreases the speed.  Then add just a single conditional entry above each Case, such as: "if (speed > 0)" and the other: "if (speed <= max_speed)". - the later is to prevent going over the max.

For the mapping to 7-segment displays:
Some chips still have there own BCD conversion instructions, check for that first, (this directly converts an 8-bit hex # into an 8-bit containing two 4-bit BCDs).  Once in BCD format a 7-segment display can be driven with old style BCD to 7-seg driver chips.

Ideas for using code:  You can split the 8-bit hex number into two 4 bit numbers (with bit shifting), then detect values over 09, subtract out the difference, pass any carry to the higher byte, recombined the numbers back to a single 8-bit, then output to BCD driver chips.  (Without the BCD chips you might think of keeping the two numbers in separate 4-bit BCD formats then use a 0-9 look up list to convert directly into a 7 segment format.)

Comment: using a if statement such as 
if (speed < 15) or
if (speed > 0) 
does not work. I have tried casting the values, but I feel I may be doing it incorrectly